# Solutions for set of Linear equations with restrains

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, systems-of-equations

I have a problem which I hope you will be able to shed some light on.

I have a set of data that i'm trying to fit into a set of linear equations.

Ax + By + Cz = D

One row of the data I want to incorporate will be represented by one equation. To solve the variables x, y, z I need a set of three equations.

The problem is, I need to set some conditions on the variables as it represents a percentage.

The two conditions set on the variables are;

x + y + z = 1

x, y, z >0

How would I incorporate the conditions unto the equations when solving it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you heard of "linear programming"? I am not fully familiar with it, but I think it deals with these types of problems. If this can be set up as a linear programming problem, then there is a famous algorithm known as the "Simplex Algorithm" which you should be able to apply to solve your problem. Sorry if this doesn't help.

Comment: Ive tried looking into linear programming and it seems possible. Still a little confused with the set up of the linear programming equation though. Should i be looking for the maximum or minimum value of X or Y or Z or do i need to introduce another variable?